FINE: GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
Getting following error when trying to hit endpoint setting bearer auth token in postmen header.
Oct 15, 2024 5:57:56 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils allocateAndReadBuffer
FINE: TCPNIOConnection (TCPNIOConnection{localSocketAddress={/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080}, peerSocketAddress={/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:52957}}) (allocated) read 252 bytes
Oct 15, 2024 5:57:56 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain execute
FINE: GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.io.EOFException
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.read(TCPNIOTransport.java:586)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleRead(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:51)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleRead(TransportFilter.java:149)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.SameThreadIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(SameThreadIOStrategy.java:79)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:66)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:391)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:360)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:324)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:255)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
What may be the cause of the issue?
I have following dependencies in pom.xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.teiid</groupId>
            <artifactId>teiid-client</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codejargon</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluentjdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

       

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>32.0.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.220</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-proxy-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.39.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.39.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
      


